# Dont have access to "Popularity Trends" but can access "Popularity and Search Reports"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, site-collection

So I am trying to see the popularity trends for my Sharepoint 2013 online site, and no matter where I try to access it for, top level site or subsites, I get the "Access denied, request access" page. However when I navigate to the top level site settings I **can** access "Popularity and Search Reports" under "Site Collection Administration" but "Popularity Trends" under "Site Administration" brings me to the request access page.

According to the Office Admin Center I am a member of Sharepoint Administrators, and when I check my permissions for a library it says I am a member of "Sharepoint Owners".

We are using Office 365, and our sites are all 2013. We currently have only a single site collection with virtually nothing on it, we only recently got Office 365 and are currently still in the process of moving everything over to it.

Is there a simple set of permissions I am missing or something? Googling hasn't helped and I didn't find any similar questions on here.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me personally. One place where I worked edited the site owner permission removing the power called "create a subsite". These people were prevented to check the popularity and search reports, getting the error you described, despite being able to do anything else a site owner could do (beside creating a subsite). I have no idea what is the connection between being able to create a subsite and check the popularity trends but this was what I noticed.

However if you are site collection admin, you have a superior level that cannot be customized. You might want to check if you really have this level or the site owner level has been customized.

Also the stats are updated once a day, so to be able to see the stats you need to wait 24 hours.

Comment: When i go to Admin center it says my role is "Global Administrator" which should include site collection. looking at site collection administrators in sharepoint however only shows "Company Administrator"